# Does printf %s on char *ptr deference it?

Tags: c, printf

I'm not sure if there exists a similar question, but

```
char *ptr = "xyz";
printf("%p\n", ptr);
```

prints an address, but 
(note the format specifiers)

```
char *ptr = "xyz";
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

prints the string?

So far what I've learnt is that printing `ptr` would give the address, and printing `*ptr` would give the value.
I'm quite confused.

Comment: You pass the address to `printf()` in both cases, but with `%s` it is dereferenced to print the string, with `%p` it is not, but the address itself is printed.

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "printing a pointer"? The whole "printing" thing entirely depends on _the way_ you want to print stuff, aka on the algorithm used to do this. You can print the address as an integer, you can print some bytes (or bits, or ...) stored at this address, you can print the data stored there until some other condition is met, you can use the data in this address to index into an array and print data from there, you can "print" it like you want to. So, "printing" a pointer doesn't necessarily print the address.

Comment: Using `%p` prints the address (which is the value of the pointer), while `%s` prints the pointed-to string (and, yes, dereferences).  This is another manifestation of the key distinction between *the pointer* (`%p`) versus *what it points to* (`%s`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check about the format specifier(s).

For `%s`, with `fprintf()` family, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> `s`
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.<sup>280)</sup> **Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.** [...]

and, for `%p`,

> `p`
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

So, basically, yes, when you attempt to print the content, you have to dereference the pointer (anyway).

Answer (score 0):

When you print with %s in C. You are printing an array of characters up to the first '\0' by definition of what a string is in C. So you actually use the adress of the first character and the printf will deference it away.

This means that

```
char *ptr = "xyz";
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

will print from the address of the ptr until the first cell from ptr where `ptr[x] == '\0'`

Answer (score 0):

When using `"%s"` then `printf` will in essence loop over the string to print it character by character, until the string null-terminator character is found.

For that it needs to use array indexing, which indeed dereference the pointer.

With `"%s"` then `printf` uses the value if where the pointer is pointing at. With `"%p"` the value of the pointer itself is used.